# What does replace --error option in sonar-scanner cli?

Tags: sonarqube, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, sonarqube-scan

That option is no longer supported, does anyone knows a new way to show errors in stdout from sonar-scanner command line interface ?

```
$ sonar-scanner -e -X -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarqube.com -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_TOKEN
INFO: Option -e/--errors is no longer supported and will be ignored
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that no replacement is needed. Quoting https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SQSCANNER-23 :

> - the '-e' option is useless and must be removed (probably deprecated for backward compatibility)
> - exception message must always be logged
> - exception stacktrace is logged if non-MessageException or if sonar.verbose is true